# Convert repeating "if" to "loop" instead (javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, loops

I have JSON data coming with values like: `status -> pla -> wea -> wea_0 -> stat`

They're a series of `wea_0, wea_1, wea_2,...` inside `pla`

And I try to check if `stat` from them is `acte`

Here's my code:

```
if (status.pla.wea.wea_0.stat === 'acte') {
    save_acte();
} else if (status.pla.wea.wea_1.stat === 'acte') {
      save_acte();
} else if (status.pla.wea.wea_2.stat === 'acte') {
      save_acte();
} else if (status.pla.wea.wea_3.stat === 'acte') {
      save_acte();
} else if (status.pla.wea.wea_4.stat === 'acte') {
      save_acte();
} else if (status.pla.wea.wea_5.stat === 'acte') {
      save_acte();
} else if (status.pla.wea.wea_6.stat === 'acte') {
      save_acte();
}
```

Please help me to turn this to `loop` or `for` instead.

Comment: Does the `wea` object contain any properties other than the `wea_num` properties?

Comment: Do you control the source of the JSON data? Ideally those values should be in an array in the first place - if you're using numbered properties there's a 99% chance you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the `wea_x` as properties with dynamic name:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  if (status.pla.wea[`wea_${i}`].stat === "acte") {
    save_acte();
  }
}
```

Comment: This also works to me. Now I know how to manipulate with those name in JSON. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array with all the possible indices of `wea_*` in it and iterate over that, checking each `wea_*` entry in turn. For example:

```js
const status = {
  pla: {
    wea: {
      wea_0: {
        stat: "blah"
      },
      wea_1: {
        stat: "blah"
      },
      wea_2: {
        stat: "acte"
      },
      wea_3: {
        stat: "blah"
      }
    }
  }
};

function save_acte(i) {
  console.log('saved acte ' + i);
}

[0,1,2,3].forEach(i => status.pla.wea['wea_' + i].stat === 'acte' ? save_acte(i) : '');
// or, if you're not using IE
[...Array(4).keys()].forEach(i => status.pla.wea['wea_' + i].stat === 'acte' ? save_acte(i) : '');
```

Comment: This example only runs up to 3 instead of 6. You may say it is nitpicking, but increasing the numbers make it more obvious that using the syntax `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` is not very scaleable.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn possibly nitpicking, but not an unreasonable comment. I've modified the code with something which is scalable (as long as don't use IE). There's no doubt that yours is the better answer; I did consider deleting this but thought it showed a different approach so was worth leaving in.